# Dollar sign in image title works in preview, but not in actual post

Tags: bug, mathjax, images, markdown, markdown-preview

I was just trying to clean up [Understanding why $\pi_{3}(N) = \mathbb{Z}_{(2n, n^2)}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373106/understanding-why-pi-3n-mathbbz-2n-n2) , which was originally almost entirely cut-and-pasted images without any alternate text.  For the first image, I gave it the alternate text:

> Arkowitz and Golasinski - Co-$H$ structures on Moore spaces of type $(G, 2)$, p. 673

This worked fine in the preview, but, when I posted the change, everything after the first dollar sign (including the trailing `/>` of whatever HTML is generated by the Markdown processor) had escaped into the text of the post.  Since my instinct was to leave a clean post, I fixed it (removed the dollar signs) and didn't get a screen shot, so I'm afraid I can't document beyond just this description of what happened.  (Because I did it within the grace period, I think that the original error won't even show up in the revision history; and it seems that editing again just to artificially re-insert, and then fix, the error would not be appropriate.)

Why does the preview handle this correctly, but not the main post?

Comment: This bug report by Glorfindel (on [meta.se]) seems related: [MathJax wrongly rendered when used as alt text for image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327908)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, in fact, [it](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4729/dollar-sign-in-image-title-works-in-preview-but-not-in-actual-post#comment24062_4729) seems identical.  Shall I close as duplicate?  (I feel like we've had this exchange about a previous bug report of mine that was also duplicate before, but I don't remember and can't immediately find the result ….)

Comment: You can't close a question as a cross-site duplicate, it's fine to leave it open. I'll link your question in my bug report, so that the developers can mark it [meta-tag:status-completed] when they get to it.